# No display with 20.04 and Intel GPU drivers

Tags: drivers, 20.04, display, intel-graphics, nomodeset

I'm currently using Ubuntu 20.04 on a new PC build with a Intel G6400 (using UHD610 graphics) and a AsRock B560M PRO4 motherboard. My display loses signal on boot when using the Intel GPU drivers, and I am only able to boot with either the nomodeset or i915.modeset=0 options.

Upon looking on my journalctl logs, I found that it gave me this error:

```
[drm:drm_calc_timestamping_constants [drm]] *ERROR* crtc 51: Can't calculate constants, dotclock = 0!
```

I've tried reinstalling the Intel drivers, a newer kernel version (5.11) and a fresh install, but the issue still persists. Furthermore, while doing my fresh install, I found that I also needed to have nomodeset enabled to actually have a display from my bootable USB as well.